# SQLite 'No such table error'

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to create tables in my `DBhelper` class and I'm continually getting this error: "No table created PAYEES".

Because of this, the rest of the DB operations are also not working. I have put sufficient time on proof reading my `CreateTableQuries`. Here is one of my queries that fail:

```
private static final  String tbl3_create_string = "CREATE TABLE "+tbl3_name+" ( "+col1_tbl3_name+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            col2_tbl3_name+" TEXT, "+col3_tbl1_name+" TEXT )";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    try {
        db.execSQL(tbl1_create_string);
        db.execSQL(tbl2_create_string);
        db.execSQL(tbl3_create_string);
        db.execSQL(tbl4_create_string);
        db.execSQL(tbl5_create_string);
        global=1;
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Log.e("DB: OnCreate Method ", e.getMessage());
        global=0;
    }
}
```

When I check this on SQLite's query validator it is working.

Comment: Can you add the code where you created the table?

Comment: By using a test variable and changing its value inside onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) method, i realized that onCreate is not being called at all. Is the problem lies there? If yes then any suggestion to check/solve?

Comment: Well, the `onCreate` is only called the first time the app is installed. Try uninstalling the app, and then add some logging to show if the table is created.

Comment: Can you show the whole class?

Comment: Your suggestion worked mattfred, thank you. I did not know the concept about onCreate()

Comment: Great. I'll add it add it as an answer.

Comment: @user3319128, Can you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107044/no-such-column-exception-sqlite/31107518#31107518 my answer for the same

Answer (score 0):

`onCreate` in the `dbHelper` class is only called the first time the application is installed. If you have made updates to this class, either uninstall the app and reinstall it, or the more correct way, change the version number and the `onUpdate` method will be called. Also add some logging to make sure it is running.

Comment: You dont have to reinstall the app for that..You can just  call the onUpgrade method with a new version and in the onUpgrade method add code to drop the old table.

Comment: That is correct. I have updated my answer.